# How to stop php script from appending error to the browser?

Tags: php, email, error-handling

I am new to PHP. Please excuse if the question is pretty obvious. This is my code -

```
$giftAssocs2 = UserGiftAssoc::getUserGiftAssocs($userid);
$newmailer = new MAIL_CLASS;
$newmailer->sendMail($giftAssocs2 , "Hello", 'xxxx@gmail.com', $mailID);
return $giftAssocs2;
```

First line is able to fetch the details properly. However mail does not send due to some smtp host related errors. Coming from the java background , I expect to see some error in the console since I have not handled the exception. However my result is like this -

SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. {"status":"true","msg":"success","details":[{XXX}]}

So I get the error appended by the actual result. I was wondering how is this possible and how to avoid this ?

Comment: by fixing the error

Comment: Or `if($newmailer->sendMail($giftAssocs2 , "Hello", 'xxxx@gmail.com', $mailID)) { return $giftAssocs2; }` or `sendMail()` might throw an exception so `try/catch` not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It probably makes sense, if you're expecting it to sometimes error, to use a [try/catch](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

If that doesn't work for you, you can use [the dreaded `@`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) to make sure the error doesn't get shown:

> PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.

So for example:

```
$sent = @$newmailer->sendMail($giftAssocs2 , "Hello", 'xxxx@gmail.com', $mailID);
if($sent) {
    //...
```

The reason I say it's "dreaded" is that you're basically saying "I don't really care if this works", and usually, instead of using the `@`, you'd use a try/catch.